# using awk to get column values and then running another command on values and printing them

Tags: unix, hash, scripting, awk

I've always used Stack Overflow to get help with issues but this is my first post.  I am new to UNIX scripting and I was given a task to get values of column two and then run a command on them.  The command I am suppose to run is 'echo -n "$2" | openssl dgst -sha1;' which is a function to hash a value.  My problem is not hashing one value, but hashing them all and then printing them.  Can someone maybe help me figure this out?  This is how I am starting but I think the path I am going is wrong.

**NOTE:** this is a CSV text file and I know I need to use AWK command for this.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; { print $2 }'
     while [ "$2" != 0 ];
     do
         echo -n "$2" | openssl dgst -sha1
     done
```

This prints the second column in it's entirety and also print some type of hashed value.

Sorry for the long first post, just trying to be as specific as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need `awk` just for extracting the second column. You can do by using `bash` read built in and setting the `IFS` to the delimiter.

```
while IFS=, read -ra line; do
[[ ${line[1]} != 0 ]] && echo "${line[1]}" | openssl dgst -sha1
done < inputFile
```

You should probably post some sample input data and the error you are getting so that someone can debug your existing code better.

Comment: This seems to do what I want.  Say I wanted to print the other columns as well and just add this as a new column, would I then have to used awk?  Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanOuellette, no, you already have all the values you need: `(( ${line[1]} != 0 )) && sha=$(openssl dgst -sha1 <<< "${line[1]}") || sha=""; printf "%s," "${line[@]}"; echo "$sha"`

Comment: Awesome, this looks like the second part to my question.  Happen to know why there is a repeating output of the hashed?  for instance: ` 1654353205839179796,2083,7051,95230376,-1,53211239,2286,Mon Jul 01 13:30:02 PDT 2013 (stdin)= 29957e719443bb2580bebd604693afbdb3b5d53f,(stdin)= 29957e719443bb2580bebd604693afbdb3b5d53f `

Comment: @glennjackman It seems that it working now oddly enough.  Not sure why it was printing the values I stated above yesterday.  thank you so much for the help!  btw...what dopes line[@] do?  Is it looking at the line that it is currently on in the loop?  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk '{print $2}' file | xargs -n1 openssl dgst -sha1
```

Use `awk` to print the second field in the file and `xargs` with the `-n1` to pass each record separately to `openssl`.

If by `CSV` you mean each record is seperated by a comma then you need to add `-F,` to `awk`.

```
$ awk -F, '{print $2}' file | xargs -n1 openssl dgst -sha1
```

Comment: I like where this is going and it seems to be somewhat the same thing that I want to do but for some reason, it will not read the file when I execute the script.  It seems to give me directory not found to the right of the original column data